# How can I set up alarm in CloudWatch for SMSMonthToDateSpentUSD?

Tags: devops, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-sns, aws-pinpoint, cloudwatch-alarms

I'm trying to create an alarm on CloudWatch with SMSMonthToDateSpentUSD. However, when selecting the metric, this metric does not appear. I've tried several ways, but nothing happens. Does anyone know how I can create an alarm or a metric for the alarm with the month's expenses in Pinpoint SMS?

- I have already tried to create a new SQL query;
- I have already tried to create a new metric;

All without a solution.